# Q1: When one instance of Termux is running, how to launch a second instace? - Q2: If two instancies running, is there a way to merge the two shells?

Tags: termux

My installed Termux is currently blocked, not working due to problems of a process the shell is executing and additionally because the shell  itself is in the SIGSTOP state.

On the one hand I would like to continue the current work by the second instance of Termux. The existing data could be used.

On the other hand I would easily raise the SW blockade if I would be able in one shell to read the PID and to kill the PID in/of the other instance's shell. I.e. as if the shells of the two Termux instances would be the shells of two windows under Konsole in KDE.

How to do?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This is quite easy, once you find out how. The Termux Wiki's [User Interface](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/User_Interface) page has the details.

To summarise, there's a "navigation drawer" which allows you to create multiple sessions and switch between them. Swipe inwards from the left edge of the Termux window to access it. It shows you a list of the current sessions, whose default names are `[1]`, `[2]`, `[3]` and so on, along with two controls. `KEYBOARD` toggles the on-screen keyboard on and off, and `NEW SESSION` creates a new session.

From within a Termux session, `ps` will list the processes of that session, `ps -e` lists the processes in all the Termux sessions, and `ps -ef` shows more complete information about the same set of processes. There's also `top` available, which may well help your find out which process to kill.

Comment: == 16.12.23 11:30 thanks, I will use this when Termux is running again. But I think we have a missunderstanding: You mean within one Termux instance to run multiple shell instances, each one called a session. I need to launche a second Termux. Regards

Comment: There doesn't *seem* to be a way to launch a second Termux. However, it appears that the Termux supervisor is a separate process from the bash shell that it runs. Have you tried launching a second session within your stuck Termux?

Comment: == 18.12.2023 16:05:: thanks to john dallman. But I do not understand your "have you tried launching a second session session within stuck  Termux?" -- Fact is: Termux presents only running crazy vim. In this vim I can come into the Ex-cmdline by ":".  There I can execute shell commands  by prepending them with "!", e.g. "!ps:.Within Termux (ordered by start time) folliwing processes are running: login-bash_1, vim, bash_2, bash_3, my ps.  bash_3 not sure, not always. All these stages are self-relaunching. If I kill one, it revives and revives its children. ..continue

Comment: == 18.12.2023 17:35 ..continueing:: I need to act from outside of Termux effecting Termux and what in Termux runs. I have installed all 3C-tools, 3C Task Manager etc. I can kill Termux. If I type on Termux icon, Termux runs again with the described problems. I think, Termux to know that it has to run in the same kind again, can have this knowledge only from cashe. But if I clean cashe by 3C App Manager Termux makes again all the same: runs vim, runs all processes revivable. My agenda: I will try to clean cashe in another way.  Regards

Comment: *But I do not understand your "have you tried launching a second session session within stuck Termux?"* What I meant was: Start Termux. Swipe a finger across the screen, starting at the left edge of the Termux display. Does a menu of sessions pop up?

Comment: == 19.12.2023 01:40:: Thank you for having recalled swipe gestures. I have lost uncountable many emails after gestures were invented in email clients. Now, in this case, swiping from left edge to right opens a side menu. On top is "[1]", i.e. one shell level, called one session. At bottom two buttons: "keyboard" and "new session", If I hit right button a new session is created with "[2]". Both sessions have the same behavior with revivable processes. The terminal names differ: /dev/pts/0, /dev/pts/1. In the neantime I have made cache clean by  settings of Android, yields 0 B. No help. Regards.

Comment: == 19.12.2023 20:25 I am about to find the cause. There is an error message "E282: Cannot read from "~." ". This comes from vim. vim is being executed with the command line: "vim -u  ~.". This means vim cannot read the .vimrc file. I dont know since when and why the complete file path specification does no more exist. Now, how to kill processes. In the Ex-cmdline of vim executing bash commands:  set priority of vim to lowest value; then killall -9 -g vim; This kills all, even Termux is no more running. No Termux window more ...

Comment: == !9.12.2023 21:10 cont. No Termux window more. In Android settings -> Apps -> storage -> cache clean. I clean cache. 0 Bytes is displayed. Then to begin again, I hit the Termux icon. Then all is the same again, Termux running with the described processes with all described problems. Open question: where is that stored, that Termux despite cleaned cache starts with the same behavior. Regards

Comment: == 21.12.2023 14:20 Found somewhere in Internet that "Failsafe" mode is possible. Tried. Invoked below of Termux a bash session in "Failsafe". Moved "vim" to another name. Proved, was done. Result: In this Failsave shell vim cannot be executed more. But in other bash sessions and if Termux is  invoked anew, vim is no more renamed, and all problems again. Next steps and next questions: I will write a new post: "When restoring Termux from a backup, how can I specify which shell Termux to use (sh or bash or ...) and how to specify which init files this shell to use?" Regards

Comment: == 25.12.2023 10:40 after some measures, problems continue, but differ: I have temporarily restored a Termux from the second last backup. by this I have with tar deleted the archive member in the last backup archive: "./usr/bin/vim". Then I have re-restored the last backup. Now process vim cannot be perpetually relaunched after killing it. Now it is login shell and  process less. The processes below Termux in start-time order are: login shell, less +G, sigsus, my ps. I am afraid that, if I would remove member less from archieve, another process would be relaunched continuously. Regards

Comment: == 26.12.2023 13:20 The first shell below Termux has the PID of session leader, calked SID. I have managed to write a shell script which gets the SID and which then kills all processes below SID by means of pgrep -d " " -P $WE_sid. Ru

Comment: == 26.12.2023 13:20 The first shell below Termux has the PID of session leader, called SID. I have managed to write a shell script which gets the SID and which then kills all processes below SID by means of pgrep -d " " -P $WE_sid. Executing this script in SID shell it does what it should do but additionally it kills the SID shell. Then the SID shell and all processes below are re-launched, revived, all with new PIDs, also the SID shell with new PID. That should not be. Is that a bug? Is there a way for me to heal the defficiency or have I to wait for the developers? Regards